# deactivate parser for some special place in the page

Tags: php

how can deactivate parser for some special place in the page ,
for example if i have some php or javascript code in my database , and retrieve them in page, they do not execute!!
another example is facebook status ,when it post ,facebook ignore any kind of code like html,php,javascript and etc

for example : i have this :

```
<?php for($i=0 ; i <= 5 ; i++){ echo $i; }?>;
```

then i see smth like this in browser :

> 012345

how can i prevent executaion of this code (instate of 012345 , show me `<?php for($i=0 ; i <= 5 ; i++){ echo $i; }?>;`)

Comment: If you are retrieving PHP code from MySQL, you will get it as a string and in order to execute it you will need to use the eval() function. However, this function should almost never be used, so please give us more details about what exactly you want to do.

Comment: what i need is what exactly facebook status done!!ignore all code parsing!!

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Where do you get PHP code from and what are you trying to do with it? An excerpt from your code would be helpful.

Comment: It sounds that you are looking for a way to prevent the retrieved code from being executed? In that case, look for [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) and alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing that you're talking about **escaping HTML**:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($stringContainingCode);
```

See http://php.net/htmlspecialchars and [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: no!!i knew this function but it's just for html part , i need any kind of function that don't let execute php , javascript and etc code !!!

Comment: @Nima Did you try it? You can be certain that `&lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;` will not be executed.

Comment: @Nima No code is ever simply *executed* just because it's in a string. Your PHP code probably "disappears" because it looks like an HTML tag to the browser (`<?php ?>`). That's where `htmlspecialchars` helps too. Try View Source in your browser, you'll see the code right there. It's not "executed".